# Dev Express XAF/EF WCF Service to handle dynamically generated queries

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, devexpress, xaf

I want to evaluate the feasibility of writing a WCF service for my DevExpress XAF/Entity Framework  Winforms application to use.

Dev Express suport [for this question](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q432017) indicates that this would be quite difficult, because XAF uses dynamically-generated queries to select and modify data.

Never the less, I am wondering how to go about it.

I have thought of simply connecting to the remote database without having a middle tier, but [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106565/secure-connectionstring-in-winform-applications)  makes me think that this would be unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with creating a WCF service with XAF. In fact [DevExpress have documented the steps](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument113439). The dynamically created queries are passed to the middle-tier for security checks and execution and the results are returned.

But as it stands, the middle tier functionality is in beta and **does not support EntityFramework**, only XPO (and it does not look like it's made it into 15.1 which <strike>will be released soon</strike> has just been released).

Note can also [access the XAF middle tier data via OData](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/eaf/archive/2012/12/12/how-to-configure-the-xaf-middle-tier-security-service-and-deploy-it-in-the-cloud-for-further-use-by-desktop-xaf-and-mobile-dxtreme-clients.aspx). Again, only XPO for the time being.

Comment: Sadly this isn't my answer because I want to use Entity Framework.