# How to implement Rijndael (AES) algorithm to encrypt C# Windows Form C# app.config

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption, rijndael

I'm thinking if it's possible to implement Rijndael algorithm so that it can encrypt the connection string in the app.config file.

For example if I will run the program at first it will automatically change the connection string to an encrypted string.

Comment: What kind of security do you think this will add?

Comment: @CodeCaster to be honest I'm on research/planning stage right now.

Comment: Alright let me revert the question: what are you trying to protect, from whom, in which situation? Also, what did your research show up? If you're going to distribute an application with an embedded connection string, then that string is not secure and trivially obtained from the running executable.

Comment: I will distribute it to other users from other locations.

Comment: Then you should not let your application connect to the database directly.

Comment: So the best way is to create a webservice?

Comment: Without any more information, I would hint towards that, yes. See also [Secure ConnectionString in WinForm Applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106565/secure-connectionstring-in-winform-applications).

Comment: Okay here is the project info: The desktop application will get the username and password of the user and then be redirected to the website. So there is already existing database for the website using MYSQL and I will create desktop application to connect.

Comment: Can you please edit all that information into your question?

Comment: @CodeCaster I think I'm leaning towards using webservice. I'll just create separate question later.

Comment: Just be sure to do your research first and not ask a question that has already been answered before, read [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than doing this yourself, you could use ["Protected Configuration"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to encrypt your configuration file.

Although this is primarily designed for use with ASP.Net, you can also use it for Windows Forms (and other) applications.

[Here's a (fairly old) article about using Protected Configuration with a Windows Forms application on Code Project.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15392/Implementing-Protected-Configuration-With-Windows)

[And here's a more recent article.](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/598863/EncryptionplusDecryptionplusConnectionplusStringpl?msg=5179670#xx5179670xx)

Comment: but Protected Configuration will only work on same network? what if I need to distribute it to users in different network?

Comment: @newuser1 The second link to an article (I just added) seems to suggest that you can use it for a distributed app.

Comment: Ok I'll look upon it. But will you suggest encryption after you read my conversation with CodeCaster?

Comment: @newuser1 No, I would not suggest using encryption in this way if it is possible to use an alternative, for the reasons outlined by CodeCaster.