# Encrypt App.Config Custom Element using cmd

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config, app-config, aspnet-regiis.exe

I am able to configure the Connection String Encryption using the **`aspnet_regiis.exe`** command. Now I have created the Configuration Section on which it is added Custom Configuration Element Collection and this will store the value of Connection Information.

```java
namespace ExpressSnapSortCreation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This Class hold the the Collection of Cofigration key 
    /// </summary>
    internal class ServerReplicationsCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This Will return the ConfigurationElement 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>ConfigurationElement</returns>
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new ServerReplicationsElement();

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Get Element BY key 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="element"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((ServerReplicationsElement)element).Name;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This is override on the Elements 
        /// </summary>
        public class ServerReplicationsElement : ConfigurationElement
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Name of the Element 
            /// </summary>
            [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]

            public string Name
            {
                get { return (string)this["name"]; }
                set { this["name"] = value; }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Data base name
            /// </summary>
            [ConfigurationProperty("connectionString", IsRequired = true)]           
            public string ConnectionString
            {
                get { return (string)this["connectionString"]; }
                set { this["connectionString"] = value; }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Data base user name 
            /// </summary>
            [ConfigurationProperty("providerName", IsRequired = true)]

            public string ProviderName
            {
                get { return (string)this["providerName"]; }
                set { this["providerName"] = value; }
            }         

            /// <summary>
            /// Display Order 
            /// </summary>
            [ConfigurationProperty("order", IsRequired = false)]

            public int Order
            {
                get { return (int)this["order"]; }
                set { this["order"] = value; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code of the Section Creation

```java
  class ServerReplications : ConfigurationSection
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The name of this section in the app.config.
        /// </summary>
        public const string SectionName = "ReplicationConfigurationSection";
        /// <summary>
        /// Replication data base name 
        /// </summary>
        private const string ReplicationCenterCollectionName = "ReplicationDataBases";

        [ConfigurationProperty(ReplicationCenterCollectionName)]
        [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ServerReplicationsCollection), AddItemName = "add")]
        public ServerReplicationsCollection ReplicationDataBases { get { return (ServerReplicationsCollection)base[ReplicationCenterCollectionName]; } }        
    }
```

This is my App Config file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
            <section name="ReplicationConfigurationSection" 
          type="ExpressSnapSortCreation.ServerReplications, ExpressSnapSortCreation" />
      </configSections>
      <ReplicationConfigurationSection>
        <ReplicationDataBases>
          <add name="ApplicationServices"  connectionString="Data Source=PC-002\SQLEXPRESS2014;Initial Catalog=AML25;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=StItS!@#SeRvErPC-003" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" order="1" />
          <add name="ApplicationServices2"  connectionString="Data Source=PC-004\SQLEXPRESS2014;Initial Catalog=AML26;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=StItS!@#SeRvErPC-002" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" order="2" />
        </ReplicationDataBases>

      </ReplicationConfigurationSection>
      <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
      </startup>
    </configuration>
```

In the Application we are getting the The value of the connection string. Due to Security purpose We can't Show the Data in App.config value. then it is required to encrypt the below Section

1. This is the first command I used

   `aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "ReplicationConfigurationSection" "C:\Users\mukesh.singh\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AML\ExpressSnapSortCreation"`

Got Error Convert the file name "app.config" to "Web.config"

> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler
>   for ReplicationConfigurationSection: Could not load file or assembly
>   'ExpressSnapSortCreation' or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.
>   (C:\Users\mukesh.singh\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\AML\ExpressSnapSortCreation\bin\Debug\web.config line 4)
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'ExpressSnapSortCreation' or one of
>   its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Failed!

2. **After changed**

> Could not load type 'ExpressSnapSortCreation.ServerReplications' from
>   assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

3. I tried this combination also

   `aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "ExpressSnapSortCreation.ServerReplications/ExpressSnapSortCreations" "C:\Users\mukesh.singh\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AML\ExpressSnapSortCreation`

Comment: You can't use aspnet_regiis.exe to encrypt an app.config file. What you can do is encrypt it via a little code.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203578/encrypting-sections-and-or-settings-in-an-app-config-file-that-will-be-redistrib?rq=1

Comment: Thanks dbugger it is working for me. I am Trying to encrypt the data using  cmd now i am able to solve it.

Comment: @dbugger If i want to do the Encryption of window Service App.Config How To Implement this code. in service i am not able to encrypt the Section.  Can you help me on that.

Comment: Ask another question -- though, it works the same way.

Comment: I try it but it not working for me.  giving error  _An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll

Additional information: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for ReplicationConfigurationSection: Could not load file or assembly 'ExpressSnapSortCreation' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified._

Comment: This issue is now fixed after Review the the code. It has some Wrong code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is The code I have Used to encrypt my custom section on the app.config. I just open the app.config file inside the Bin folder it is Encrypted

```
  Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("ReplicationConfigurationSection");
            if (section != null)
            {
                if (!section.IsReadOnly())
                {
                    if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
                    {
                        if (!section.ElementInformation.IsLocked)
                        {
                            section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");
                            section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
                            Console.WriteLine("Section {0} is now protected by {1}",
                                section.SectionInformation.Name.ToString(),
                                section.SectionInformation.ProtectionProvider.Name.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

When I open the Config file its look Like this

```
    <configuration>
  <configSections>
        <section name="ReplicationConfigurationSection" type="ExpressSnapSortCreation.ServerReplications, ExpressSnapSortCreation" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>

  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
  </startup>
  <ReplicationConfigurationSection configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
          </KeyInfo>
          <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>FXUE9iChoq/7HGE4nV3muaPZy4ejcDCcZx0PVasHZJi4xRs0ZPXI08unUegvXs+C2FALEskpHa+Tt4u24I8OhSRS9QI+I2kpgxTlQvMFmsvFu6pkDQS1jt13EHmov0Thr1CBGhMXyHMm0EGr0+yWKI3PfD9vwGmQl0yawLdyiockQk9kCuik8g8jnpiyaidYL/RKpdwNPBuH9wOm8WWTXlUL4N+SO98jAX0PPoDjaDbDdB14t71Favg7vxpjIj5pDlljj59ek3pudW0etIHm6v8YsJaE9Et62DfzB31W4kmGNgmmGWTu4/hF93J0kv9VgkmKTcdOmeXq2KHA2JCLKg==</CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>JkWK1jpOzcbtX8k/SVvTVRxQKO0ylRyWQ8imAOaIz51e3JmdhqXgdH8p5unceEiLCH2PTZOBZMIgYW4hYILiGnUE4SBZ6PfFr2vGowXdg13K808uSAx9taFb0HfvubcSQ23nwoBuJJmKfYooZX73YRnRvxIFH5SJZZ+WB8mTlNgaAZ+JftaN2rAlpH/cei4gwPCR64PaTu5VDJflSj0WnF7ZD13c0I0ZpHtJs29u0XTkBnAsL5DGULZsAexn2+89uaLfNpr9K+AYW8477TelVpnHGsMGDSOYOlWNUylldjATKZ/sgzDU/gq29dV+9RO18xvCHLXWjKKiT4B7UOlp82/1D/ky3OlK6opCEIJbCStm0q8MrvSQksdPN/yJ+S0Tv3E8hD4Wmf6grJOBlMGesomickqOzEudc+3fRwQS4Paf+ca3NgAk5utI+piZNhNtAnA/XU1ozDD0Zv381xaMTOTNjBq35hplK8zuHBVg+bZkbilSd3L4x4QAEv1Ds9Kt5hyUZyUNMWoXUXk0qoOP8UbMdHvUGvjsvAFudvZ7ZxtntiARptTFeTfg3qcghDdoyzOYBK3Md2urstEVdsdj6z6/RqBFO4qGY6hQ/IvIq+7lgG2rDsGH3AJlRNSdb+YJYktqGut65kvqcrSR2CgtYoGWcsUneBkpzQ65Rb0d6jL2Qt7zfJg1aA2iv97N15+tPjFDUQbbYFBi2ubvq1/pc7s/odaSUNK2LCfctXFG32MbEndJk1rXreLencAH/KlO2iJzA6QujwcT/LYo6w97lVbkrZAWWgxnUmVKeq+OwS6AybaK/sIw5wxBFsouCNdt</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </ReplicationConfigurationSection>
</configuration>
```

For More.

1. [Encrypting sections and-or settings in an App.config file that will be redistributed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203578/encrypting-sections-and-or-settings-in-an-app-config-file-that-will-be-redistrib?answertab=active#tab-top)
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider(v=vs.80).aspx